# CSS minify and rename with gulp

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-watch

I've a variable like

```
var files = {
    'foo.css': 'foo.min.css',
    'bar.css': 'bar.min.css',
};
```

What I want the gulp to do for me is to `minify` the files and then `rename` for me.

But the tasks is currently written as (for one file)

```
gulp.task('minify', function () {
    gulp.src('foo.css')
        .pipe(minify({keepBreaks: true}))
        .pipe(concat('foo.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});
```

How to rewrite so it work with my variable `files` defined above?

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking to iterate the properties of your 'files' object?  (PS: Is there a reason it is an object? I might have expected this to be an array, based on its name..?)

Comment: Just an FYI `gulp-minify-css` has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) in favor of [gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css)

Answer (score 63):

You should be able to select any files you need for your src with a Glob rather than defining them in an object, which should simplify your task. Also, if you want the css files minified into separate files you shouldn't need to concat them.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('minify', function () {
    gulp.src('./*.css')
        .pipe(minify({keepBreaks: true}))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    ;
});

gulp.task('default', ['minify'], function() {

});
```

Comment: When I do this, it's creating new files with .min.min.css each time I save. Why is it doing that?

Comment: On src, you can always specify files to ignore using "!".

Example (you want to exclude all *.min.css files on your css folder and subfolder:

`gulp.src(['css/**/*.css', '!css/**/*.min.css'])`

Answer (score 15):

I tried the earlier answers, but I got a never ending loop because I wasn't ignoring the files that were already minified.

First use this code which is similar to other answers:

```
//setup minify task
var cssMinifyLocation = ['css/build/*.css', '!css/build/*.min.css'];
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
  return gulp.src(cssMinifyLocation)
    .pipe(minifyCss({compatibility: 'ie8', keepBreaks:false}))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(stylesDestination));
});
```

Notice the `'!css/build/*.min.css'` in the src (i.e. var cssMinifyLocation)

```
//Watch task
gulp.task('default',function() {
    gulp.watch(stylesLocation,['styles']);
    gulp.watch(cssMinifyLocation,['minify-css']);
});
```

You have to ignore minified files in both the watch and the task.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have done

```
var injectOptions = {
     addSuffix: '?v=' + new Date().getTime()
};
```

Then

```
return gulp.src('*.html')
    .pipe(wiredep(options))
    .pipe(inject(injectSrc, injectOptions))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
```

end result is unique timestamp added

Example in index.html

```
   <script src="/public/js/app.js?v=1490309718489"></script>
```