# Gulp-sass - remove path of file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm using gulp-sass to compile scss into css and have managed to get it working somewhat. At the moment this is the code i have setup in my gulp file:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./popup/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css'))
});
```

The only issue I have is when it compiles into css files instead of just creating a index.css file in the dest ./build/css it appends a whole tree of folders that mirrors the tree where the file came from. So for example if one of my files lives in `app\src\scripts\components\app\new-ticket\css` then in the build folder will be the same tree: \src\scripts\components\app\new-ticket\css with the file in the last folder.

Is there a setting or a way I can remove the path in gulp-sass so i'm just left with build/css/index.css but keep the same path structure where the .scss files live?

Comment: Thing you are looking for is `concat`, here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273358/gulp-minify-all-css-files-to-a-single-file

Comment: If you want to answer the question with that ill mark it as correct!

Comment: sure. Just added as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another `pipe` to add `concat`. This function takes a destination file name to generate one css (or) js file.
Here is the code:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./popup/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(concat('index.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css'))
});
```