# Compile all css files into one css file in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to learn Gulp. Got a gulp watch fine and can easily compile scss to css. This is all working.

I am stuck now though.... How can I compile multiple css files into one css file?

I am currently using:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/css/*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss('styles/bundle.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});
```

But it's not working. All that keeps happening is my app files (`main.css` and `section.css`) are output in my dist folder (this is correct) but not in one file. They are just simply compied instead of both being compiled into a `styles.css` file for example.

Thank you for any suggestions. As I say, I am trying to learn Gulp. I thought I had been doing well until this.

Comment: Long shot: maybe there's no "styles" folder? Based on the folder structure on the other files. Try with `.pipe(concatCss('dist/css/bundle.css'))`

Comment: try 'app/css/**/*.css'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273358/gulp-minify-all-css-files-to-a-single-file